# How to use Future query Nhibernate in case of many to many association

Tags: c#, .net, linq, hibernate, nhibernate

I have many to many relationship between student and courses.

```
public class Student 
{
    public virtual Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Name {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<Course> Courses {get; set;}
}

public class Course
{
    public virtual Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Name {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<Student> Students {get; set;}
}
```

These entities has corresonding tables including a many to many table for CourseToStudent.

I want to write most optimized query using Nhibernate future to get Course or Student.

I am aware I can use future in one to many but how can we use future to write many to many query.

For example for some one to many query Semester to Course. 1 semester can have many courses but 1 course can belong to only one semester.

So I can write future query as

```
Semester= _repository.Future<Entity.Semester>(_repository.Query<Entity.Semester>().where(x=>x.Id = semesterId));

Course= _repository.Future<Entity.Course>(_repository.Query<Entity.Course>().where(x=>x.Semester.Id = semesterId));
```

But I am confused how to use future in case of many to many. Can anyone explain me if I should use future here or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your questions, that you want to select students for concrete semester, than you can use something like this:

```
session.Query<Student>()
    .Where(s => s.Courses.Any(c => c.Semester.Id = semesterId))
    .Future();
```

Or

```
session.Query<Course>()
    .Where(c => c.Semester.Id = semesterId)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Students)
    .Future();
```